# Issue with "make distcheck" in GNU autotools project relating to generating a manual

Tags: man, automake, software-distribution

I'm using `autoconf` and `automake` to build a tiny project.

For the project's manual, I've used OpenBSD's native [`mdoc` format](http://man.openbsd.org/mdoc), and the installable `man`-formatted manual is generated from this using [the `mandoc` utility](http://man.openbsd.org/mdoc).  The `man`-formatted manual will be installed as the actual manual with `make install`, as some systems do not grok `mdoc` properly, or at all.

In the project's `doc` directory, I have a `Makefile.am` file that currently looks like the following (the manual is for a utility called `shell`):

```
dist_man1_MANS= shell.man
EXTRA_DIST=     shell.mdoc

shell.man:      shell.mdoc
        $(mandoc) -T man shell.mdoc >shell.man
```

`$(mandoc)` will be properly expanded to the full path of the `mandoc` formatter (this variable is set by the `configure` script).

This allows me to run `make dist` which creates `shell.man` and then creates a compressed `tar` archive containing both the source `mdoc` manual and the generated `man` manual along with the rest of the project's distribution files:

```
$ tar tzf shell-toolbox-20180401.tar.gz
...
shell-toolbox-20180401/doc/Makefile.am
shell-toolbox-20180401/doc/shell.man
shell-toolbox-20180401/doc/Makefile.in
shell-toolbox-20180401/doc/shell.mdoc
```

This `tar` archive can later be used to successfully build and install the project, and its manual. So far so good.

However, if I run [`make distcheck`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Checking-the-Distribution.html) (because I'd like to make sure it absolutely positively works):

```
$ make distcheck
...
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for mandoc... /usr/bin/mandoc
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/shell
Making all in src
Making all in doc
/usr/bin/mandoc -T man shell.mdoc >shell.man
mandoc: shell.mdoc: ERROR: No such file or directory
*** Error 3 in shell-toolbox-20180401/_build/sub/doc (Makefile:459 'shell.man')
*** Error 1 in shell-toolbox-20180401/_build/sub (Makefile:345 'all-recursive')
*** Error 1 in /home/myself/local/build/shell-toolbox (Makefile:576 'distcheck')
```

It seems as if the source `mdoc` file is not available in the build directory when the manual needs to be built:

```
$ ls shell-toolbox-20180401/_build/sub/doc
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  myself  14989 Apr  1 21:35 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  myself      0 Apr  1 21:35 shell.man
```

The zero-length `shell.man` file comes from the failed `mandoc` run.

The source is available in the unpacked archive, but just not copied over to the `_build/sub/doc` directory:

```
$ ls -l shell-toolbox-20180401/doc
total 48
-r--r--r--  1 myself  myself   178 Apr  1 21:23 Makefile.am
-r--r--r--  1 myself  myself 13925 Apr  1 21:23 Makefile.in
-r--r--r--  1 myself  myself  3443 Apr  1 21:27 shell.man
-r--r--r--  1 myself  myself  3319 Apr  1 18:54 shell.mdoc
```

**Question**: What `automake` magic do I have to apply to get `make distcheck` to properly copy the `mdoc` source to the build directory before it attempts to generate the `man`-formatted manual?  I'm looking for a "proper" way of doing this, not a hack.

I tried using

```
man1_SOURCES= shell.mdoc
```

but that makes `automake` complain with

```
doc/Makefile.am:2: warning: variable 'man1_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
doc/Makefile.am:2: library has 'man1' as canonical name (possible typo)
```

---

Another way to provoke this error is to manually do a [VPATH build](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/VPATH-Builds.html) (which is basically what's happening when doing `make distcheck`):

```
$ make distclean
$ mkdir t
$ cd t

$ ../configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for mandoc... /usr/bin/mandoc
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/shell

$ make
Making all in src
Making all in doc
/usr/bin/mandoc -T man shell.mdoc >shell.man
mandoc: shell.mdoc: ERROR: No such file or directory
*** Error 3 in doc (Makefile:459 'shell.man')
*** Error 1 in /home/myself/local/build/shell-toolbox/t (Makefile:345 'all-recursive')

$ ls -l doc
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 myself myself 14589 Apr  1 22:42 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 myself myself     0 Apr  1 22:42 shell.man
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:  To properly pick up the source for the manual when performing a VPATH build, the rule for it in the relevant part of the `Makefile.am` file should look like

```
shell.man:      $(srcdir)/shell.mdoc
        $(mandoc) -T man $(srcdir)/shell.mdoc >shell.man
```

By specifying `$(srcdir)/shell.mdoc`, `make` will find the file in the distribution tree even when the build tree is in a different location from the distribution tree.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an accepted answer but I think the following rule might work in the VPATH build and it also have the advantage that it is smaller:

```
shell.man:      shell.mdoc
        $(mandoc) -T man $< >$@
```

Answer (score -1):

`automake` supports `-local` and `-hook` rules that get run before and after some of the various targets. There is apparently no `distcheck-local` so another idea would be in your `Makefile.am` to use the `dist-hook` to run something after the `dist`:

```
dist-hook:
        cp something $(distdir)/somewhere
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only copies the before the distribution archive is created. When the actual build happens, the file is not in the `_build/sub/doc` directory.